# What are the differences or possible relationships among syndetic sets, thick set, intermittent set, dense set, normal set?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, measure-theory

This thought may be silly and not correct at all. From my understanding, syndetic set is larger than thick set. Because any finite shifts will make syndetic set cover $\Bbb{N}$, but thick set just has arbitrarily long interval however, it is still of finite length. intermittent set is the set of disjoint intervals, i.e. A is intermittent set if A=$\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty(a_i,b_i)$, and ($a_i,b_i$) are disjoint intervals $b_i-a_i\rightarrow\infty$, so syndetic set is as large as intermittent set? Our professor just gave us the definition of dense set in [0,1], which is a set B is a dense set in [0,1] if every subset of [0,1] will contain an element of set B, so is B normal in terms of 0-1 sequence?

Also what are their corresponding upper density? Do they have natural density?

Comment: You seem to be talking about two different things here, subsets of $\Bbb N$ and subsets of $[0,1]$, and there is no obvious relationship between the two.

Comment: Every intermittent set is clearly thick, but the converse is not true: $$\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}[3n,4n]\cup\{5n:n\in\Bbb N\}$$ is thick but not intermittent, since it has infinitely many intervals of length $1$. A syndetic set need not even be thick: the set of even natural numbers is syndetic but not thick.

Comment: Yes, I realize I had some confusion about what kind of set I am talking about previously. Thank you very much!